# Parsing a Python JSON

Tags: python, json

I am trying to parse the below JSON, and extract name and interval from the elements.

```
reply "[ {
  "interface" : [ {
    "name" : "ethernet39",
    "number" : 39,
    "rate" : [ {
      "interval" : 45,
      "rx-bad-vlan-rate" : 0,
      "rx-broadcast-packet-rate" : 0,
      "rx-byte-rate" : 0,
      "rx-drop-rate" : 0,
      "rx-error-rate" : 0,
      "rx-multicast-packet-rate" : 0,
      "rx-unicast-packet-rate" : 0,
      "timestamp" : "2015-06-18T21:59:23.703Z",
      "tx-broadcast-packet-rate" : 0,
      "tx-byte-rate" : 0,
      "tx-drop-rate" : 0,
      "tx-error-rate" : 0,
      "tx-multicast-packet-rate" : 0,
      "tx-unicast-packet-rate" : 0
    }, {
      "interval" : 45,
      "rx-bad-vlan-rate" : 0,
      "rx-broadcast-packet-rate" : 0,
      "rx-byte-rate" : 0,
      "rx-drop-rate" : 0
...
```

I've tried the following:

```
  for x in range(0,len(interfaces)):
    for interface in interfaces[x]:
      entry = {}
      entry['name'] = statistic['name']
      for interval in statistic['rate']:
        entry['byte_rate'] = interval['rx-byte-rate']
        entry['packet_rate'] = interval['rx-unicast-packet-rate']
        entry['timestamp'] = interval['timestamp']
        entry['droprate'] = interval['rx-drop-rate']
        entry['errorrate'] = interval['rx-error-rate']
    entries.append(entry)
```

However, I always get an error that 
TypeError: string indices must be integers

What am I doing incorrectly? In the code, interfaces is a JSON acquired by doing json.load()

Comment: You may want to show the error trace. [ask]

Answer (score 2):

The "interface" and "rates" dictionary values are lists, so you need to index into them.

```
print("name = {}".format(reply["interface"][0]["name"]))
rates = reply["interface"][0]["rate"]
for rates_index in range(len(rates)):
    print("rate = {}".format(rates[rates_index]["interval"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't is supposed to be interface instead of statistic ??

```
for x in range(0,len(interfaces)):
    for interface in interfaces[x]:
      entry = {}
      entry['name'] = interface['name']
      for interval in interface['rate']:
        entry['byte_rate'] = interval['rx-b
```

Comment: Yes it is, but this doesn't make a difference; same error at same place. Good catch though